# Retrieve rows that do not exist in table

Tags: mysql, ms-access

So I have 2 tables:

> gym(ID*, name, type)
>   gym_unlocked(ID*, gymID*, userID*)

I am trying to perform an SQL query that will only retrieve rows from the gym table if it does not exist in the gym_unlocked table.

So for instance, if I have 1 row in the gym table with a name of "FirstGym" and type of "Strength" and if the ID of that gym does not match any row in the gym_unlocked table given that userID is 2 then it will retrieve the row from the gym table.

So far I have:

```
SELECT        ID,name,type
FROM            gym
WHERE gym.id NOT IN gym_unlocked.gymID AND gym_unlocked.userID = 2
```

However it doesn't work, so is their any way I can achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not that familiar with mysql syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT ID,name,type
FROM gym
WHERE gym.id NOT IN 
(SELECT gym_unlocked.gymID
FROM gym_unlocked
WHERE gym_unlocked.userID = 2)
```

I suppose you are getting an error about gym_unlocked table. You need to use either a LEFT JOIN for this table or a SUBSELECT in order to make a connection with that table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g.ID, g.name, g.type
FROM  gym g
left join gym_unlocked u on g.id = u.gymID
                        AND u.userID = 2
WHERE u.gymID is null
```